# I am using mouse pointor for workspace switch is there any shortcut to it?

Tags: workspaces

[image]

I have to move the mouse pointer to the icon to get it open.

Comment: Your picture does not seem to illustrate what you are trying to do, but from the description it seems that you are looking for this information [https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowKeys</kbd> to move around between workspaces.

For example, to move one workspace to the right, just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrow</kbd>.

These are set in your Keyboard Preferences, which can be accessed by opening your Dash, searching for **Keyboard**, selecting **Shortcuts**, and then **Navigation**.

[image: Navigation menu with Switch To highlighted]

From here, you can also set hotkeys to move to a specific workplace if you'd rather do that instead of switching one at a time. You can see these at the bottom of the above screenshot (*Switch to workspace n*).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key</kbd> will move between workspaces.